# Apache beam throws Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured error when PubSub is a dependency

Tags: apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have observed that Apache Beam throws `Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured` error when `google-cloud-pubsub` (0.21.1-beta in my case) is a dependency. Is there a workaround for this that doesn't involve removing `google-cloud-pubsub`.

Apache Beam version - 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue from my Windows 10. 
I added the following to the VM options and it resolved the problem.
-javaagent:\jetty-alpn-agent-2.0.6.jar